# sorting order unaffected by LC_ALL

Tags: linux, sort, locale

I'm experiencing a problem with sorting order. 
With this sample file the sort order on my local environment differs from any other system I tested this on. The locales are the same on both systems. What else could be the culprit?:

```
control
ற_matched
ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿ ಸಂಭವಿಸು
```

In my case there is no difference between `C` and `en_US.UTF-8` where everywhere else I see a different sorting order.

```
jglapa@sheep:[~]: sort testfile
control
ற_matched
ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿ ಸಂಭವಿಸು

jglapa@sheep:[~]: LC_ALL=C sort testfile
control
ற_matched
ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿ ಸಂಭವಿಸು

jglapa@sheep:[~]: LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort testfile
control
ற_matched
ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿ ಸಂಭವಿಸು
```

where on any other system I tested, the output is :

```
ubuntu@other:~$ sort testfile
control
ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿ ಸಂಭವಿಸು
ற_matched

ubuntu@other:~$ LC_ALL=C sort testfile
control
ற_matched
ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿ ಸಂಭವಿಸು

ubuntu@other:~$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort testfile
control
ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿ ಸಂಭವಿಸು
ற_matched
```

`locale` command on both system shows the same settings:

```
jglapa@sheep:[~]: locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

ubuntu@other:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Systems: `Ubuntu 19.10 18.04`

```
jglapa@sheep:[~]: LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 locale title
English locale for the USA
jglapa@sheep:[~]: locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_AT
de_AT.iso88591
de_AT.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Comment: What OS versions do these systems have?

Comment: @bk2204 it's Ubuntu 19.10 and the remote is 18.04 but I had the same behavior before upgrading 19.10 when it was 18.04. I think my locale are somehow corrupted, tried reinstalling but nothing helps.

Comment: Is the `en_US.UTF-8` locale enabled (does it show in the output of `locale -a`, what does `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 locale title` say?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I provided the info the issue description. The locale is enabled